# why extra character appearing in a string if the string is used again?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

In my windows application, i am getting the server name from the user and stores it in a string(say servername).while using this string in connection statement extra '\' character is coming and it can be seen while executing in debug mode
here i gave the servername as ADMIN\SQLEXPRESS
while executing, the servername is showing 2 slashes instead of one. ie the value becomes ADMIN\SQLEXPRESS
whats the reason?

Please help me

Comment: dont worry. two slashes in fact is one slash. thats because slashes are used for escaping characters. like `\n`,`\r`,etc... but if you want to represent slash it self you must write two \\

Comment: If you feel duplicate does not cover your case make sure to search for similar topics i.e. https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+string+double+slash+debug, also same topic comes up all the time with quotes - you can tweak your search to include that too.

Comment: but while executing, the connection string raises error.

Answer (score 6):

`\\` is an [escape sequence character](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) which represents backslash (`\`) for regular literal strings.

Let's say your string is;

```
var str = "ADMIN\\SQLEXPRESS";
```

You see this string as `ADMIN\SQLEXPRESS` in debugger.

If this is confuse you, you can use with one backslash with [verbatim string literal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) as;

```
var str = @"ADMIN\SQLEXPRESS";
```

Comment: i tried with \\ but it doesnt work.I need to set a variable with value ADMIN\SQLEXPRESS and it sholud be assigned in connection string.what to do?

Comment: @SrinathKamath I don't feed I understand your question clearly. Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  in your question?